# PYTHON Name 'x" is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I continually receive an error: `NameError: name 'text' is not defined`

```
def Encryption(i, j):
    diction = {'a':'x1', 'b':'3', 'c':'lk', 'd':'$%', 'e':'^%', 'f':'(*', 'g':'-+', 'h':'il', 'i':'z@', 'j':'@#', 'k':'}{', 'l':'-*', 'm':'p', 'n':':l', 'o':'!#', 'p':'1%', 'q':'k<', 'r':'/', 's':'>', 't':'@', 'u':'if', 'v':'q#$', 'w':'^#1', 'x':'5-=', 'y':'n?', 'z':'v'}
    my_text = input("What would you like to encrypt?")
    text = my_text.lower()
    for diction in text:
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    Encryption(text,diction)
```

The Error message, in full:

```
File "Spy1.py", line 39, in <module>
  OpSet()
File "Spy1.py", line 3, in OpSet
  MainMenu()
File "Spy1.py", line 16, in MainMenu
  Encryption(text, diction)
```

NameError: name 'text' is not defined 
I'm trying to get the program to read a user's input, and translate it into the alternate set. However, it won't work.
I can't identify the source of this "naming" issue, as I've attempted to define Text previously but it will not work.

I've found no adequate explanations of the order of definitions beyond hacks, either.

Thanks!

Comment: identation issue at last line.

Comment: Don't overwrite the variable text in the loop. Use a different local variable

Comment: Guys it is his first question, stop downvoting, maybe he is 13, and you are judging like a badass teacher.

Comment: use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: Looking at the error message, you appear to call `Encryption` from `MainMenu`. You have not shown that piece of code, but very likely, `text` is not defined in `MainMenu`.

Comment: You also have an infinite recursion loop in `Encryption`: you're calling `Encryption` from within the function itself, with no means of leaving the function. At least, if the indentation is correct as it is now (see comment by Surinder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
def encrypt(toEncrypt):
    d = {'a':'x1', 'b':'3', 'c':'lk', 'd':'$%', 'e':'^%', 'f':'(*', 'g':'-+', 'h':'il', 'i':'z@', 'j':'@#', 'k':'}{', 'l':'-*', 'm':'p', 'n':':l', 'o':'!#', 'p':'1%', 'q':'k<', 'r':'/', 's':'>', 't':'@', 'u':'if', 'v':'q#$', 'w':'^#1', 'x':'5-=', 'y':'n?', 'z':'v'}
    temp = toEncrypt.lower()
    toReturn = ""
    for l in temp:
            toReturn += d[l]
    return toReturn

encrypt('test') # returns '@^%>@'
```

`def encrypt(toEncrypt)` the var `toEncrypt` is the argument or input

`d = { ... }` is the dictionary `d['a']` will return `x1`, `d['b']` will return `3`

`temp = toEncrypt.lower()` sets `temp` to a lowercase version of `toEncrypt`

`toReturn = ""` defines a new blank string outside of the for loop

`for l in temp:` loops through each of the characters in `temp`

`toReturn += d[l]` `l` is used as a key for dictionary `d` and returns the corresponding value

`return toReturn` is the functions return ... or output

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything, though I don't fully understand the function of "toReturn+= diction[letter]". Is this adding letters to the previous string? EDIT: Actually, this does exactly what I wanted it to do. Could you explain how the adding works, though? Thank you!

Comment: I changed my code to make it easier to understand.  `toReturn += d[l]` is the same as saying `toReturn = toReturn + d[l]`  it is a form of concatenation.

Comment: Thank you! Your added explanations clarified bounds.